# Transparent water shader for EEVEE?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine, transparency

I followed a simple "how to make water in EEVEE" tutorial on youtube, but I don't know how to make it transparent. My current node setup:

[image]

**Q:** How to get the water transparent?

Comment: You can turn down the waters alpha or mix it with a transparency shader

Comment: Hi and welcome! Just to let you know (since part of your question): This is no regular forum rather a Q&A site. Suggest take the [tour] to learn about how this site works, also I recommend read about [How do I ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For EEVEE:

1. Turn “Transmission” all the way up.
2. Turn alpha down to about 0.5
3. Set blend method to either hashed or blend.

Comment: Today, I might plug a Frensel node into the alpha socket instead of just setting it static.